# Create tabs for each month

Tags: php, html

I am using [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_tabs_open) example to create tabs for each month in a year.

This is the tab links:

```
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'År', 1)">Januar</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'År', 2)">Februar</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'År', 3)">Mars</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'År', 4)">April</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'År', 5)">Mai</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'År', 6)">Juni</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'År', 7)">Juli</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'År', 8)">August</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'År', 9)">September</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'År', 10)">Oktober</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'År', 11)">November</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'År', 12)">Desember</button>
</div>
```

It has total of 12 tabs, and I want each tab to display value from SQL where **datetime** column is equal to that month. This is an example on how the date is stored: `2020-09-02 11:42:58`.

I think I am into something here, but not sure how to proceed:

```
<?php
            
  $sql = "SELECT ident,COUNT(*) FROM sales WHERE YEAR(date) = YEAR(NOW()) AND MONTH(date) = ?";
  $stmt = $link->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bind_param("i", $_POST['month']);
  $stmt->execute();
  $result = $stmt->get_result();
  foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo "<div id='{$row["i"]}' class='tabcontent'>";
    echo "<h3>Current month is {$row["i"]}</h3>";
    echo "<p>Some text here.</p>";
    echo "</div>";
  }
            
?>
```

So when clicking each tab, I want a text to display "This is month (and then the monthname)".

But that is not happening. When I open the page, I just get the following error below the tab:

```
Notice: Undefined index: i in /storage/ssd3/537/14310537/public_html/statcs.php on line 413
```

EDIT:

```
id | ident |        date
--------------------------------
1  | KAMIL | 2020-09-02 11:42:58
2  | KAMIL | 2020-09-01 16:37:45
3  | KANN  | 2020-08-18 22:32:41
4  | ARBI  | 2020-08-21 13:15:33
5  | KANN  | 2020-08-21 14:12:58
6  | KAMIL | 2020-08-21 14:13:05

So in this case: 

KAMIL has 2 sales in September
KANN has 2 sales in August
ARBI has 1 sale in August
KAMIL has 1 sale in August
```

Comment: You don't have a column called `i` in your resultset.

Comment: @Dharman Hm. But `div id='` should be equal to each month from the tab, where 1=Januar, 2=Februar and so on.. How would you do it?

Comment: Then you want to use the value of `$_POST['month']`, but beware of XSS.

Comment: So you mean `$row["ident"]` because you select a column called `ident`

Comment: @Dharman I tried that now, and got following error: `Current month is
Notice: Undefined index: month in /storage/ssd3/537/14310537/public_html...`

Comment: You only have two columns in the SQL `ident,COUNT(*)`. There is no `i` or `month`. You need to explain what you are trying to achieve. Where should the value come from?

Comment: @Dharman The tables contains over 200 rows. And the columns are id, ident and date. Each user has a ident, and the date column is the date when the row was added to the table. So I want to count all the rows for each user, and display them in a tab. This is an example on how I want it to look: https://i.ibb.co/wzczGDw/Untitled.png. And if the user click on another month, it will display the values from that exact month (where date column is equal to current month).

Comment: Can you show us your table schema or sample row values? The image you showed is not even close to what your code is trying to display. It's difficult for us to understand where the username or the month name should come from.

Comment: @Dharman I edited my answer, please look at the edit. Maybe that is better :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly That JS function is taken from w3schools. You can see it when you open the link from the question

Comment: @Dharman Thanks, must be going blind :)

Comment: Except the one on W3Fools has 2 params and this one must have 3. This puts us into the "They probably did..." Which is an assumption which is normally dangerous and wastes lots of time

Comment: Param 2 of `openCity()` should be the Month Name you have `'År'` for all months

Answer (score 0):

Since the month number comes from your POST variable then you can use that and the `DateTime` class to get the name of the month in your locale.

In your SQL you should group by the user, since you want to get a count of sales for each user.

In your loop you can then display the values as follows:

```
$sql = "SELECT ident, COUNT(*) 
    FROM sales 
    WHERE YEAR(date) = YEAR(NOW()) AND MONTH(date) = ?
    GROUP BY ident";
$stmt = $link->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("i", $_POST['month']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

$month = date_create_from_format('n-d', $_POST['month'].'-01')->format('F'); // get textual name of the month
foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo "<div class='tabcontent'>";
    echo htmlspecialchars($row['ident']).' has '.$row['COUNT(*)']. ' sales in '.$month;
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Comment: The function `date_create_from_format` gives me error: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function format() on boolean in ... 418 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in ...`

Comment: Are you sure you are passing the right value to it? It works for me: https://3v4l.org/b4tGI

Comment: Not sure if its because I've been awake for 20 hours, but I cant figure this out. Are there any other solutions to create a tab view like the photo I posted?

Comment: You need to go to sleep. Please come back tomorrow. It is not wise to stay awake for so long and you can't perform mental tasks properly when you are tired. Please, take some rest.

Comment: Might this be a good solution: https://pastebin.com/YdmfttQ1 ? To hardcode each month, and then add PHP code for each month inside each `<div`.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not understand what you are saying. Which part of the application do you have a problem with? SQL, PHP, HTML or JavaScript? Please focus on one at the time. Your HTML is already hardcoded as I understand from the question. PHP is executed on server side and it handles the request received from the client. Are you receiving the posted values correctly? Is your SQL returning any values?